# In textbox unable to use the string '6' in robot framework

Tags: unix, robotframework

In robot framework I'm trying to type the string 'r16Ed' as username in textbox.
now its trying r6 and the tab to password field and type the string Ed as **.
It seems number 6 act as TAB.If I give the string 'Admin' it is typing properly.

Any other way to fix it.I also tried press keys that as well not working as expecting

By below code is

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary

*** variables ***
${URL}   http://testDomain.com
${Browser}    chrome
${Username}  r16Ed


*** Test Cases ***
Testing with Browser
    [Documentation]    Launching the browser
    LaunchBrowser    ${URL}    ${Browser}
    click element     xpath://input[@id='userid']
    input text     id:userid  ${Username}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when executing Android tests. The solution was put some delay between each character. I created a for with a small delay and typed char by char